# How to verify that manifest is embedded

Tags: windows, visual-studio, manifest

I'm trying to embed the application manifest into an executable using visual studio 6.  How can I verify that the manifest was successfully embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quiet old and quiet cool tool named [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) where you can check the resources of your PE file (aka exe). This is in my opinion the simplest way to check this.

Another unsafe option would be to open your program with a text program like notepad there you just need to look for your XML, but keep in mind that it is stored as UTF-16 so there will be spaces between each char.